# Date range selector similar to Google Analytics date range selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker, google-analytics

I'm building a web app where the vast majority of our target audience likely have experience with Google Analytics - and as a part of that website there is a date range selector.  I was hoping to find an off-the-shelf javascript/jquery date range selector to customize to my needs, but I'm not a fan of the stock version that jquery provides because it lacks the actual date inputs, it only has the two visual calenders.  I listed what I'm looking for below.

**What I'd love:**

- Select a start and end date on a
  single calender (preferably with two
  months shown).
- Enter the start and end date manually
  into an input box
- Highlighting of selected date range
  (changing background-color of dates
  within 'start' and 'end').
- Fairly easy to get at the CSS /
  layout elements

**What I don't need:**

- A timeline selector
- Compare to past

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: If my answer was what you were looking for please accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery-ui-datepicker

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#multiple-calendars

here is also a listing of other plug ins

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/8-Widely-Used-Calendar-Date-Picker-and-Time-Formatting-jQuery-Plugins-that-Web-Developers-Should-Know.aspx

Comment: are you kidding ? did you try to compare these two widgets. Try to select date range in "Google analytic" and "jQuery UI DatePicker"

Comment: kidding? Check out the second link, you can grab a plug in that will add a date range to it. Please read someones answer and verify before marking the answer down. http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Comment: you are right, second link has something similar which google has, BUT "jQuery UI date range selector" totally different. it does not has so much feature what google has.

Answer (score 5):

jquery-ui-datepicker do not have date range selector. Just found out this nice plugin which does that - http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/

**update**

Recently started using another open source plugin and it's working great too.

https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

Answer (score 2):

I like this one due to the quick select of common ranges such as year to date, today etc. The code looked pretty readable, so i guess it would be possible rewrite it slightly to align with use cases for the application.

http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker_v2/